# Why can I use a variable before declaring it in JavaScript / TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

To my understanding, after ES6 and the introduction of `let` and `const`, a variable declared with them must be declared before it's used. However, I have run into many examples where my code runs just fine when I declare the variables after its use. For example, this is the code from (a simplified version of) the TypeScript template of React Native:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text} from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Some text</Text>
    </>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
  },
});

export default App;
```

Here, `styles` are declared after they are used, and it even seems to be the idiomatic way to do it, but even ESLint highlights as [`no-use-before-define`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-use-before-define).

My question is: why does it still work?

Comment: Because that code doesn't get executed top-to bottom line by line. The `App` constructor is one of the last things that is called...

Comment: By the time you *call* `App()`, `styles` has been defined.

Comment: Although compiled it is not like other language, eg C++, where the compiler doesn't recognise variables until they are declared in the document top to bottom, variables aren't considered to be used until the program calls the function at run time.

Answer (score 1):

You **aren't** using it before it is declared.

The variable isn't used until the function it is used inside is **called**.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially what is happening is

`const styles = StyleSheet.create({});`

has been declared *as a* called function. So on declaration the function is run, the variable is assigned the object;

`const App = () => {return()};`

is declaring App *will be* a function, the constructor for this will be called when it is executed from the Main process and currently you are just exporting it from the module. So at the point of export Styles has been declared with the object returned, and App has been declared awaiting future execution.